# Android appcelerator titanium Program Running Issue?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, sample

i am very New to Android apps in titanium i create the one sample project sucessfully after installing the Windows7 when i run the application in the Android emulator i got the following issue:

```
 [ERROR] 'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    [ERROR] operable program or batch file.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
    [ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.1.GA\android\builder.py", line 2236, in <module>
    [ERROR]     s.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.1.GA\android\builder.py", line 2006, in build_and_run
    [ERROR]     for avd_props in avd.get_avds(self.sdk):
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.1.GA\android\avd.py", line 23, in get_avds
    [ERROR]     for line in run.run([sdk.get_android(),'list','target'],debug=False).split("\n"):
    [ERROR] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
    [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination.
```

Process exit value was 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Titanium is having trouble finding a file related to the SDK or the emulator. Titanium is fairly complicated to get set up and running (although it has improved recently). Make sure to follow each and every step in the instructions ( http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Quick_Start) because missing even one will cause an error like the one you have.

Check out this link specifically: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio-section-30086257_SettingupTitaniumStudio-AndroidSDKConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Set your Path according to this: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables
I am sure this will solve your problem. I solved my issue From this link no other else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and adding this to the beginning of PATH environment variable fixed it for me:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```

I hope this helps.